# Android HTTP POST request to server (need explanation)

Tags: java, android

```
        URL url = new URL("url");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);// i can delete this nothing happens
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(valueIWantToSend);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

This code above post my value: valueIWantToSend to my server. Everything is working fine, but i want to ask: Why then i remove this line:

```
 Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

Nothing is shown on my server, but then i add this line everything is working great, but why ?  I am not using Reader in this connection so what i miss understood?

Comment: `conn.setDoInput(true);`. If you say that you are gonna do it you have to do it.

Comment: If i delete this nothing change, still need Reader

Comment: are you sure about your server side? how do you check data on server? maybe charset not compatible. use wireshark or chrome developer tools-> network tab to check what you are sending

Comment: i create txt file on server and then store my data, as i said then Reader is defined everything is printed in txt file, if no Reader defined zero nothing shown

Comment: can you try OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()),"UTF-8")

Answer (score 1):

I think u should call urlConnection.connect()

```
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();
```